# How to use Json?

Tags: php, json, curl, decode, twitch

This is my PHP Code for get top 5 twitch clips. How do I get **slug** or another info (Or **name**) from this? Can not figure it out

```
$clientid = 'My-Client-ID'; 
$url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/clips/top?limit=5&channel=twitch'; // sets the url for the request

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // sets the url in the curl object
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERRER, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Client-ID: " . $clientid, "Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json")); 
$data = curl_exec($ch);

$json = json_decode($data, true);
```

https://pastebin.com/s7GwsZ6f Results from above this

How do i get **slug** or **name** (I want 5 last clips)

Answer (score 1):

`$json` is an associative array. Which is basically what other languages call a Map or dictionary. You can access attributes in `$json` by doing something like `$val = $json['key']`

to get a property of `$json` (say clips), you can do something like `$json['clips']`. This will return a list of clips. You could then loop through thought clips and find a particular "slug".

My only question is... you want the last 5 clips, shouldn't your API call only return 5 (i.e ?limit=5).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // sets the url in the curl object
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Client-ID: " . $clientid, "Accept: 
application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return instead of print
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($data, true);
$clips = array_slice($json["clips"],count($array)-5, count($array));
var_dump($json);
```

curl prints the results instead of returning it by default, so I added the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, also note `CURLOPT_REFERER` was misspelled, not sure if it matters or not.

I use array_slice to get the last 5. I tested the script and it works, but I didn't confirm the results so maybe I'm doing some off-by-1 mistake here - but I think you get the idea! (And I also think that [the point about limit in @James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50884665/1497533) is the better way of doing it! https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/#query-string-parameters)